# Yii2 ActiveDataProvider query by ActiveQueryInterface ( querying with relations)

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

ActiveDataProvider implements a data provider based on yii\db\Query and yii\db\ActiveQuery.

However the parameter $query implements only the QueryInterface and not the ActiveQueryInterface which is kind of strange for ActiveDataProvider!.. Is there any way to do queries with relations like this?

```
provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => MainModel::find()
              ->with("relatedModel")
              ->where(["relatedModel.something"=>$value]),
]);
```

Comment: @lin Yii is not only yii 1.x , yii2 is also part of Yii

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/yii2/info, cheers. `Yii 2.0 is a complete rewrite of Yii 1.1 based on php 5.4 improvements and aims for simplicity, performance and extensibility.`. Your question title also tell us, its about "Yii2" and not "Yii". Different Frameworks.

Comment: @lin Yii1 and Yii2 are different frameworks I agree, I know what the tags say, both of us have contributed to that tag information at various points we should know what it says. My point is Yii is also the name of the project not just Yii1. Out of 223 questions in Yii2, 90 are also tagged Yii. If you think Yii should only contain Yii1 questions( I agree there needs to be a differentiation to prevent confusion)I suggest you raise an issue in meta and have it renamed Yii1 or something similar, Like how symfony is today. otherwise it doesn't make sense to have Yii to be used only for Yii1.x

Comment: Dont mix Software-Version's with proper names. "Yii" is a proper name, also "Yii2" is a proper name. A proper name like "Yii1" or "Yii1.x" does not exists. "Yii2" does not mean "Yii 2.0", its a big difference.  I promise, every 223 question and depends on "Yii2", nobody does run "Yii" and "Yii2" framework in one application, cause its not compatible. (Maybe some questions are about Yii/Yii2 because they ask for code differences) Second its "senseless" to use more than von PHP-MVC-Framework in one application. I think you agree to this. In that way, "Yii" & "Yii2" cant be taged in one question.

Comment: @lin Actually I do run Yii2 and Yii in the same application,it is even part of the official documentation see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-using-3rd-party-libraries.html#using-yii2-with-yii1. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265845/1900483, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252988/1900483, and other questions on specific/ generic tags.I do not make the rules in SO, if you have a problem with how the version related rules are set, take it up in meta. Either way this discussion has nothing to do with my question, we can take it up in chat or IRC

Comment: Thanks for this information: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-using-3rd-party-libraries.html#using-yii2-with-yii1. Looks like we are both right ;).

Comment: :).. without that support, I would never have considered moving my projects to Yii2.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with a same problem for the last 4hours. The solution is to use **joinWith()** instead of **with()**:

```
$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => MainModel::find()
              ->joinWith("relatedModel") //here change the with() to joinWith()
              ->where(["relatedModel.something"=>$value]),
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment, I'll add an answer...

Did you test this code? This should work. Look at the [source of `ActiveDataProvider`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/ActiveDataProvider.php) at [this line](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/ActiveDataProvider.php#L131) and [this line](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/ActiveDataProvider.php#L174). They chek if `$this->query` is an instance of `ActiveQueryInterface` and do then some sort of things. Since `ActiveQueryInterface` extends `Queryinterface` your example should work. If not, what kind of error do you get?

I think if you don't use an `ActiveQuery`, you will not be able to sort easily when I look into the [`setSort` method](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/ActiveDataProvider.php#L171)...